# How do I read a xgb.plot.multi.trees plot?

Tags: r, xgboost

I've made an XGBoost model for a binary prediction. However, I don't know how to read the plot. There are multiple features in one block. I understand that the leaf at the end is an indication of how high the change is whether my prediction is true or not.

But I don't understand how the model gets there and how I can reproduce it. For instance, the PAR in the first block shows (7642). I min-maxed my data for normalization, so I don't understand how that number influences the prediction?

[XGBoost multitree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7klhM.png)

I've added my tree as an image, so my main question is how can I read this tree so that I can e.g., reproduce it in another code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.